# Как получить адрес текущей страницы, загруженной во фрейме?

Tags: javascript

Есть фрейм с условным src="site.com". Как получить адрес страницы, если во фрейме перешли на страницу site.com/page1? Во фрейме подгружена страница другого домена.

Comment: Если там другой домен - то никак, насколько мне известно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko отчего же. Если целевой сайт не запрещает через X-Frame-Options, то адрес страницы будет доступен в .src соответствующего объекта фрейма